# Reading Excel files using python3

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am trying to read excel file using python to do some data analysis. The data file is located in the same folder as the python program. However, the code is giving a syntax error. Do not know why. Appreciate your help.

```
import pandas as pd

dataIn_df = pd.read_excel(r 'C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\data\InputData.xlsx', sheet_name='InputData')
```

```
File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\data\RateRegulator.py", line 54
    dataIn_df = pd.read_excel(r 'C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\data\InputData.xlsx', sheet_name='InputData')
                                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an extra space between `r` and `'C:\...` this is causing the `SyntaxError`.

```
r 'C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\data\InputData.xlsx'
```

should be

```
r'C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\data\InputData.xlsx'
```

Comment: @ijlalShah If the answer works for you, please mark this answer as accepted.